# What's the MAC Address of my Ethernet adapter?

Tags: windows-7, networking, mac-address

I have purchased a Dell Inspiron N5010 (with Windows 7). It works all fine but I need to know the MAC Address of the Ethernet adapter.

I have tried `IPconfig /all`, but it does not show my Ethernet adapter. How can I check and confirm my Ethernet card's physical address. I need to use a restricted LAN which requires me to know the physical address of my Ethernet adapter

Comment: usually it is also printed on a label on the bottom side of the notebook if you can find it using the operating system

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have something like Virtualbox installed (which installs its own set of virtual LAN cards), you can try typing `getmac` at the command prompt. It should provide you your LAN card's MAC address.

If you do have Virtualbox installed, you might consider running `getmac /v` instead for more verbose output. It will list down the connection name associated with the MAC address.

[image: screenshot of getmac]

Comment: LOVE IT.  Never knew this command.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure your Ethernet adapter is not disabled.

And because the output of `ipconfig /all` is too long so the `cmd` truncated the output, then you need:

```
ipconfig /all | more
```

and press `space key` to next page till you find the MAC Address.

The graphical way:

`Control Panel` => `Network and Sharing Center` => `Change adapter settings`, then right click on your network device (`Enable` it if it's disabled), `Status` => `Detail`.

Comment: did all, but no icon for local area network found nor any details. DSL connected through lan connector is working. Need to know MAC address of ethernet adapter about which no indication is seen / found in my system even though now i have installed recent drivers available with Dell.

Comment: @Khalid, I think what you meant `lan connector` is `ethernet adapter`. Your laptop has only one Ethernet adapter according to the [specs](http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/review/notebooks/dell/inspiron_15r_n5010/349068/specs)?.

Comment: My fault, I don't know LAN Connector till I checked the "dictionary", I thought it's kind of network device...